# Sampling according to difference in function value

Tags: matlab, random

I have 20 values x1,...x20. Each value is between 0 and 1, for example 0.22,0.23,0.25,...

```
x = rand(20,1);
x = sort(x);
```

Now I would like to choose one data point but not uniform at random. The data point with the lowest value should have the highest probability and the other values should have a probability proportional to the difference in function value to the lowest value.

For example, if the lowest function value is 0.22, a data point with a function value of 0.23 has a difference to the best value of 0.23 - 0.22 = 0.01 and should therefore have a probability similar to the 0.22 value. But a value of 0.3 has a difference of 0.3 - 0.22 = 0.08 and should therefore have a much smaller probability.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would leave this as a comment, but I unfortunately don't have the rep yet.
This looks interesting, and I have a few questions for you.  (I will edit this answer to be an answer later.)

> The data point with the lowest value should have the highest probability and the other values should have a probability proportional to the difference in function value to the lowest value.

Lets take an array of 20 items, and subtract the lowest number from the entire array.  This leaves us with our smallest value (which you want to be the most probable) as 0.  We need to define a function now, that goes over all of the points and integrates to 1.

I've done the following:

```
x = rand(20, 1);
x = sort(x);
xx = x - x(1);
```

I suppose at this point we can invert our answers so the lowest point is 1.

```
Px = 1 - xx;        %For probabilities
TotalP = sum(Px);
```

Now we have everything we need, I think...  So lets see what we can make.

```
P = Px/TotalP;        %This will be our probability.
SanityCheck = sum(P); %Make sure that it sums up to 1.
```

Looks like that works, so lets make our cumulative sum array, and get an element.

```
PI = cumsum(P);     %This will be the integral form of the probability function.
test = rand;   %Create a test number so we can place it in the integral function
index = find(PI > test, 1); %This will return the first entry that is greater than our test value...
result = x(index); %And here's our value
```

I hope this is along what you were looking for.  If not, please comment and I'll get back to you. :)

[edited to incorporate comments]

Comment: Good answer.  Just a few comments: (1) `rand(1,1) = rand`. You can simply call `rand` on its own with no arguments and it'll default to giving you a single output. (2) `index = find(PI > temp, 1); result = x(index);` can be replaced with `result = x(PI > temp);`  Whenever possible, use logical indexing over `find`.  It is faster. (3) Comments in MATLAB use `%`, not `#`. I've taken the liberty to change that for you. It also will allow the syntax highlighting to kick in for comments.

Comment: I appreciate the comments, and should have been a little more careful when I put this together.  One thing to note, though.  Using result = x(PI > temp); would result in an array of entries coming back rather than the first one that works, that's why I utilized find.  I guess it could be done more like rlist = x(PI > temp); result = rlist(1);  That would keep the logical indexing.

Comment: Oh shoot of course. I didn't see the `find` with `1` being the second parameter.  Yeah forget the logical indexing then.  Definitely use `find`. I misread and I thought you wanted to find all elements that satisfied the condition.  BTW, please accept my warm welcome to StackOverflow. Not many of us answering MATLAB questions here!

Comment: I really appreciate it.  Take a look at the change I made, I still used logical indexing ;)

Comment: lol. no no change it back to `find`. You only want the first entry so that is definitely faster. I misread the code. Since you only want to find the first entry, not only does it save space but it also saves time. As soon as you find the first entry, the function quits. Logical indexing will have to slice into the array and grab all entries, then you can index into that.  Octave can get away with doing it in one line like: `result = x(PI > temp)(1);`... something that I complain about daily that MATLAB does not have.

Comment: Changed it back.  I'm pretty sure python could do it like that too.  Well... Python could probably do the whole thing on a single line.

Comment: Yes it can. I'm assuming you are coming from a Python background as well as you were using `#` as comments. :)... yes, good that you changed it back. I was in error.

Comment: Thank you so much, Michael. It works very well. Just one little thing: Is it possible to punish bigger difference in function value more heavily (i.e. decreasing the probability for beeing chosen)?

Comment: If you replace Px = x - x(1) with Px = (x - x(1))^(1/2) it would punish the difference more.  Replace the square root with cube root, etc to get larger differences.